# Page speed insight shows FID & INP not applicable in desktop & mobile

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, google-pagespeed-insights-api

While checking my own website https://ensearchopedia.com on page speed insights, the below web vitals showing Not applicable for my website.

First Input Delay (FID) Interaction to Next Paint (INP)

The values appears when i check it for mobile version.

Can you suggest me how to fix this errors, Thanks in advance for your valuable input

Comment: When I [check it in PSI](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis?url=https%3A%2F%2Fensearchopedia.com%2F) I see "No Data" for "Discover what your real users are experiencing", which means that [PSI doesn't have sufficient data for that URL](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about#why-is-the-real-user-crux-data-not-available-for-a-url-or-origin) to give metric values for it. Is that what you're referring to? "Not applicable" for only FID and INP indicates there's _some_ data, just not enough for just those two metrics. Are you sure you're testing that URL?

Answer (score 0):

Not all pages will have any interaction from users. For example a simple blog site, may just have readers who open the article, scroll (which doesn't count toward FID nor INP) to read the page, and then leave the page happy.

And this may differ between mobile and desktop users (for example a user may be more likely to tap on a mobile site while scrolling).

INP is (and FID was) optional in terms of Core Web Vitals - without them a site can still be marked as passing or failing based on LCP and CLS.

Not having sufficient INP or FID data for a static-style site is perfectly normal and nothing to be concerned about. If you want to know if you have any INP or FID issues you can measure this yourself using the [web-vitals.js library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals) or any other RUM tool and you may still get sufficient data that way even if it doesn't meet the minimum threshold for reporting in CrUX. Do be aware though, that it might be skewed or highly variable in this cases if only some users are interacting and a lot are not (which is one reason why CrUX has the minimum thresholds it does, to be confident in the data it is reporting and reduce such noise).